# Favicon won't load, even when going to the direct URL

Tags: favicon

The favicon isn't working on my site. If I go to google.com/favicon.ico I see the image displayed. But for some reason on my site, lucasjohnson.co.uk/favicon.ico prompts me to download a file. I have even tried replacing my own favicon with Google's, but I still have the same problem.

Edit: The file ico file was converted from a png using Dynamic Drive's FavIcon Generator.

Comment: You need to configure your server to send the correct `Content-Type`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this but I have other sites on the server which are working ok with the favicon.

Answer (score 1):

I checked http://www.lucasjohnson.co.uk/favicon.ico, and the response content-type is `text/plain`. There are several content types that can be used for favicon, but `text/plain` is not one of them.

The most common ones are `image/x-icon` and `image/vnd.microsoft.icon`.

So basically, just choose one of the following content types and add it to your `link` tag:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="http://www.lucasjohnson.co.uk/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png"                href="http://www.lucasjohnson.co.uk/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif"                href="http://www.lucasjohnson.co.uk/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon"             href="http://www.lucasjohnson.co.uk/favicon.ico" />
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon for more details.

BTW, regardless (or not) of this problem, I've noticed that you're not closing one of your `meta` tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Comment: Is this favicon.ico file a _true_ ICON format image, or did you rename some other formatted image? It's quite unusual for a server to have trouble serving a favicon.ico file.

Comment: If you need to convert your image to an actual ico format there are several free online converters a simple google search can find, also some image editors do support export to ICO format.

Comment: I converted it from PNG with a FavIcon Generator. I still can't get it to work.

Comment: I'm looking into your web-page source - now you forgot to close the favicon's `link` tag.

Comment: Well spotted. I've closed that now. Still, I don't think it's a problem with the code because I can't even load the ico file when I browse to the URL