# Can't load Favicon in Meteor

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, favicon

I can't add a Favicon next to my website name in the tab. I have checked three SO posts and tried all possible combination. My logo.ico or logo.png file is in the "*ProjectName/public*" folder. From this folder I can access other images that load on the browser, if I link them like this:

```
<body>
  {{> carouselTemplate}}
</body>

<template name="carouselTemplate">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">

        <div id="my-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <!-- indicators dot nav -->

          <!-- wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <!-- for each slide one div [active is the first slide that is shown on the page] -->
            <div class="item active">


              <!-- #HERE -->
              <img src="/handsbwG.jpeg" alt="hands"/>
              <!-- /HERE -->


              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>TEXT</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- controls or next and prev buttons -->

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

When I go to localhost:3000/logo.ico the icon is shown (also for localhost:3000/logo.png).

Different SO References:

- [Ref 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054788/how-to-load-a-favicon-with-meteor)
- [Ref 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486290/favicon-wont-load-even-when-going-to-the-direct-url)
- [Ref 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774914/favicon-with-meteor)

Two of my Code examples:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16 32x32" href="/logo.png">

<link rel="icon" sizes="16x16 32x32" href="/logo.ico?v=2">
```

Comment: see alaning here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054788/how-to-load-a-favicon-with-meteor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file *must* to be named `favicon.ico` and nothing else. Rename `logo.ico` to `favicon.ico` and it should work.

The header links may work to point to a differently named file, but I suspect you are not putting them in the right place (meteor can be tricky in terms of knowing what will really get served as header).

Comment: I renamed it to favicon.ico and replaced href="/favicon.ico?v=2" but it still doesn't work. What do you mean with "but I suspect you are not putting them in the right place"? Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: It might be that your browser is aggresively caching the favicon.ico. Depending on the browser I've experienced difficulty in getting a new favicon to be displayed. Check out this related Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh

Answer (score 1):

[Meteor looks for all head tags and combines them to one that is sent to the client.](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates)
This is how I add in my projects,

```
client/.../partials/head.html
```

No template tags or anything else, just maybe extra head elements.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.png"/>
</head>
```

and then ofcourse have the favicon in `public/img/`

Answer (score 0):

I have try many scenario and check all answer related to this but this is not working for me,So after that i used below JavaScript code for resolved this issue.

This code is changing website favicon icon dynamically.

```
(function() {
    var link = document.querySelector("link[rel*='icon']") || document.createElement('link');
    link.type = 'image/x-icon';
    link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
    link.href = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and found that moving the favicon.ico file into the root of the public/ directory resolved this for me. No dice in a /public/img directory.

I used the below and it instantly worked; nothing further was necessary (didn't have to clear cache/history in Chrome).

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico?v=2" />
```